# How to setup hadoop without changing `/etc/hosts`?

Tags: hadoop

In order to test the network performance in our cluster, I have to deploy hadoop in the nodes. In all the setup guide that I can find, there is a step that changes `/etc/hosts` file. The problem is, the network I'm testing is not the frequently used one. So if I directly edit this file, this may cause the existing program fails.

I've tried to use ip address instead of its host name in those hadoop configuration files (`core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `mapred-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml`). For example, in `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://10.1.0.50:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hadooptmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

But this cannot work without changing `/etc/hosts`.

Is there any way to specify a host file only for hadoop?

Comment: We would appreicate if you tell what did you try to solve this problem and only then we can help. In this format, it does not add value.

Comment: Thanks jaipster. I've tried to set all the address to its ip address directly, such as in `core-site.xml`:    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://10.1.0.50:9000</value>
    </property>